# Memory leakage in deleting nested pointers in C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

Hi I have a class it contains some arrays of structures that are defined in header as following:

```
struct ball
{
    int* time;
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* vx;
    float* vy;
}*Ball;

struct team
{
    int* time;
    char* side;
    int* unum;
    int* type;
    int* state;
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* vx;
    float* vy;
    float* body_angle;
    float* head_angle;
}**TeamLeft, **TeamRight;   

struct teamscore
{       
    string name_l;
    string name_r;
    int* time;
    int* score_l;
    int* score_r;
    int* pen_score_l;
    int* pen_score_r;
    int* pen_miss_l;
    int* pen_miss_r;
}*TeamScore;

int** playmode;
```

In constructor memory allocation is performed as the following and then the structures are filled desired initial values:

```
Ball = new ball[file_num];
TeamScore = new teamscore[file_num];
TeamLeft = new team*[file_num];
TeamRight = new team*[file_num];
playmode = new int*[file_num];

for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++)
{
    Ball[i].time = new int[frames_num];
    Ball[i].x = new float[frames_num];
    Ball[i].y = new float[frames_num];
    Ball[i].vx = new float[frames_num];
    Ball[i].vy = new float[frames_num];

    TeamLeft[i] = new team[11];
    TeamRight[i] = new team[11];

    TeamScore[i].time = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].score_l = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].score_r = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].pen_score_l = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].pen_score_r = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].pen_miss_l = new int[frames_num];
    TeamScore[i].pen_miss_r = new int[frames_num];

    playmode[i] = new int[frames_num];

    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    {
        TeamLeft[i][j].time = new int[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].side = new char[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].unum = new int[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].type = new int[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].state = new int[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].x = new float[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].y = new float[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].vx = new float[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].vy = new float[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].body_angle = new float[frames_num];
        TeamLeft[i][j].head_angle = new float[frames_num];

        TeamRight[i][j].time = new int[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].side = new char[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].unum = new int[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].type = new int[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].state = new int[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].x = new float[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].y = new float[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].vx = new float[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].vy = new float[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].body_angle = new float[frames_num];
        TeamRight[i][j].head_angle = new float[frames_num];
    }
}

for (int Fi = 0; Fi < file_num; Fi++)
{
    TeamScore[Fi].name_l = "None";
    TeamScore[Fi].name_r = "None";
    for (int Fr = 0; Fr < frames_num; Fr++)
    {

        Ball[Fi].time[Fr] = 0;
        Ball[Fi].x[Fr] = 0;
        Ball[Fi].y[Fr] = 0;
        Ball[Fi].vx[Fr] = 0;
        Ball[Fi].vy[Fr] = 0;

        TeamScore[Fi].time[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].score_l[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].score_r[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].pen_score_l[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].pen_score_r[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].pen_miss_l[Fr] = 0;
        TeamScore[Fi].pen_miss_r[Fr] = 0;

        playmode[Fi][Fr] = 0;           

        for (int Ti = 0; Ti < 11; Ti++)
        {
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].time[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].side[Fr] = 'L';
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].unum[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].type[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].state[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].x[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].y[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].vx[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].vy[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].body_angle[Fr] = 0;
            TeamLeft[Fi][Ti].head_angle[Fr] = 0;

            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].time[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].side[Fr] = 'R';
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].unum[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].type[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].state[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].x[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].y[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].vx[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].vy[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].body_angle[Fr] = 0;
            TeamRight[Fi][Ti].head_angle[Fr] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In destructor pointers are deleted as following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++)
    {       
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].time;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].side;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].unum;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].type;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].state;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].x;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].y;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].vx;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].vy;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].body_angle;
            delete TeamLeft[i][j].head_angle;

            delete TeamRight[i][j].time;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].side;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].unum;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].type;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].state;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].x;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].y;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].vx;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].vy;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].body_angle;
            delete TeamRight[i][j].head_angle;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++)
    {
        delete Ball[i].time;
        delete Ball[i].x;
        delete Ball[i].y;
        delete Ball[i].vx;
        delete Ball[i].vy;

        delete TeamLeft[i];
        delete TeamRight[i];

        delete TeamScore[i].time;       
        delete TeamScore[i].score_l;        
        delete TeamScore[i].score_r;
        delete TeamScore[i].pen_score_l;
        delete TeamScore[i].pen_score_r;
        delete TeamScore[i].pen_miss_l;
        delete TeamScore[i].pen_miss_r;

        delete playmode[i];

    }

    delete Ball;
    delete [] TeamScore;
    delete TeamLeft;
    delete TeamRight;
    delete playmode;
```

still there is a memory leakage and I tested it in task manager. if big arrays are created and destroyed the program used all available RAM and the program will be terminated with unhandled error. I will appreciate if anyone can help me with the problem of destructor.

=========================================================================
Updated version of destructor which will delete all allocated memories correctly is as:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].time;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].side;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].unum;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].type;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].state;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].x;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].y;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].vx;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].vy;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].body_angle;
            delete[] TeamLeft[i][j].head_angle;

            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].time;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].side;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].unum;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].type;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].state;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].x;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].y;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].vx;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].vy;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].body_angle;
            delete[] TeamRight[i][j].head_angle;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++)
    {  

        delete[] Ball[i].time;
        delete[] Ball[i].x;
        delete[] Ball[i].y;
        delete[] Ball[i].vx;
        delete[] Ball[i].vy;

        delete[] TeamLeft[i];
        delete[] TeamRight[i];

        delete[] TeamScore[i].time;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].score_l;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].score_r;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].pen_score_l;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].pen_score_r;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].pen_miss_l;
        delete[] TeamScore[i].pen_miss_r;

        delete[] playmode[i];

    }

    delete[] Ball;
    delete[] TeamScore;
    delete[] TeamLeft;
    delete[] TeamRight;
    delete[] playmode;
}
```

Comment: You really don't have to write such complicated code in C++. Look at standard library containers such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Oh my god.... what's with all the pointers and `new` and `delete`.... this is horrible!!! No wonder you're having memory management problems......

Comment: Beyond the eye-gouging artifacts presented, "I tested it in task manager" - that should be *last* on the list of things you use to determine memory leaks on Windows. You should be using the [CRT memory facilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx). I'm also unclear as to why `Features` is even mentioned *at all* , as it has no apparent usage in either the ctor or dtor whatsoever.

Comment: @Alireza the updated destructor seems to be ok ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you allocating arrays like here:

```
TeamLeft[i][j].time = new int[frames_num];
```

but you use incorrect delete method:

```
delete TeamLeft[i][j].time;
```

You need to delete it as array:

```
delete [] TeamLeft[i][j].time;
```

and all the other arrays should be deleted similarly.

P.S.

Consider using `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays. It will save you many hours of headache :)

Comment: Thanks but memory leakage still exist. I am suspicious that some of inner pointers are not deleted properly but cannot identify where they are. I put the initializer and destructor in a loop the memroy is become full drammatically.

Comment: I know the vector facilities but want to understand the problem of this code I was using such pointer creation and deletion in C before and no problem occured.

Comment: First of all make sure you didn't miss any array and that you properly delete *all* the arrays with '[]'. When you have such a number of various 'new' calls I would assume that you missed either a `delete` or `delete []` somewhere. Second thing, please don't call for the destructor explicitly! use `myObj = new  Game();` and then `delete myObj;`

Comment: @Alireza Please see my comment above.

Comment: I used destructor as you said and I am sure that all I created by new is deleted in list above but I don't know that I correctly implement destructive section.

Comment: Thanks I checked it again and there was an array which was created and not deleted now everything works fine with 'delete []'

Comment: sure I will port it now